# looping, comparing multiple table values

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach, registration

I've been having a problem & not sure the logic I need.

I'm trying to build a basic PHP & MySQL registration page though with a check to see if they've changed IP addresses, check to see if the addresses have been registered with 3 different accounts, if so, return false.

Here is my logic.

Account registers -> Database (site_registration) -> Email verified -> Database (users) -> Account logs in -> Database (account_logins) (only if new IP)

Account tries to reregister after 3 entries -> Check Database (site_registration) IP field -> Check Database (account_logins) account IP fields -> Throw all IP's for the account into an array -> Check array against site_registration -> If IPs are found on 3 accounts, throw registration error -> Database (suspicious_logs)

This is the mysql code I need, but not sure how to loop it.

```
//SELECT * FROM users WHERE (idnumber = '75.143.xxx.xxx') OR (idnumber = '76.94.xxx.xxx') OR (idnumber = '76.94.xxx.xxx')

$username = $_SESSION['login'];
$check_ip_site = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM site_registration WHERE (username = '$username')");
$check_ip_logins = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM site_logins WHERE (username = '$username')");
$check_ip_user = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM users");

for($i = 0; $login_array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_ip_logins); $i++);
    array_pop($login_array);

for($i = 0; $user_array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_ip_user); $i++);
    array_pop($user_array);

foreach ($login_array["ip"] as $login_ips) {
    if (in_array($login_ips, $user_array["ip"]) > 3) {
        return true;
    } else { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Though this syntax doesn't work, it's what I need, I want to find if ANY of the IPs are found on 3 records in the user database, if they are return false.

Comment: the end of a `for()` should be `{` with code inside then `}` not `for();`.

Comment: You also don't need any loops; you can do this with one query.

Comment: What would that be exactly? I can't figure out the logic here. I need to compare all their IP's they've ever had to see if they've been registered to any 3 accounts, if so, return false.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me. I had to set it into a foreach for it to loop the query. Also, my for loop works like that as I had nothing to do inside of the loop. If anyone sees a better way of doing this, please let me know! Before I accept my answer, I'll see if anyone has a better solution.

```
//Check if username is set, if it's not use the current IP instead (add cookie handling later to keep from destroying evidence)
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($username == NULL){
    $check_ip_logins = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM site_logins WHERE (ip = '$ip')");
}
else
{
    $check_ip_logins = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM site_logins WHERE (username = '$username')");
}

for($i = 0; $login_array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_ip_logins); $i++);
array_pop($login_array); //Deletes the null array at the end of the for loop

foreach ($login_array as $la)
{
    $lips = $la["ip"]; //Place just the IP's into it's own array

    $check_ip_user = $MySQL->consult("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (idnumber = '$lips')"); //Loop through all IP's associated with account & check the users database

    while($test = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_ip_user)) {
        $names[] = $test["name"]; // This is used as a way to count, any thing can be used here.
    }
}
if (count($names) > 3)
{
    echo 'you have too many accounts you cannot create anymore';
}
else
{
    echo 'you are able to create an account';
}
```